# Can PyLearn do everything that Theano can?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, theano

Since PyLearn2 is build upon Theano, is it possible to do anything I can do in Theano in Pylearn2? For example, if I have some snippets of Theano code, can I run them as-is in Pylearn2, or would this not work? If it wouldn't, why not?

Comment: Off-topic: Pylearn2 is now unmaintained. You may want to look at Lasagne. You can combine between Theano and Lasagne seamlessly. For example: https://github.com/alrojo/RNNProteins/blob/master/train.py

Answer (score 1):

For your info, Pylearn2 is now deprecated. You can check it's alternatives i.e. platforms that are build on top of theano, which are: lasagne, blocks and keras.

Answer (score 0):

PyLearn2 is built on top of Theano. If you have Theano snippets you can run them with PyLearn2 snippets.